# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError) - Cucumber and Cheese example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I am new to ruby and following along Cheezy's example in his book Cucumber and Cheese.

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'page-object'
gem 'pry-debugger'
gem 'faker'
gem 'data_magic'
gem 'debugger', '1.6.6'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'activerecord', '3.2.1'
gem 'factory_girl'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

---

I have a file named database.rb (lives under support) that contains:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'sqlite3'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'sqlite3',
    :database => '../puppies/db/development.sqlite3')
```

---

My env.rb file contains:

```
require 'rspec-expectations'
require 'page-object'
require 'page-object/page_factory'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'data_magic'
require 'require_all'

require_all File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/pages'

PageObject::PageFactory.routes= {
    :default => [[HomePage, :view_details_for_puppy],
    [DetailsPage, :add_to_cart],
    [ShoppingCartPage, :complete_adoption],
    [CheckoutPage, :checkout]]}

World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

---

My class pages :

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :adoption
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :adoption
end
```

Adoption.rb

```
class Adoption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :puppy
end
```

---

I get this error when trying to run the first CRUD scenario:

```
test_puppies_one djLaX805$ bundle exec cucumber -t @crud1

uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
/Users/djLaX805/RubymineProjects/Learning Ruby on a MAC/test_puppies_one/features/support/pages/database/adoption.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/require_all-1.3.2/lib/require_all.rb:109:in `require'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/require_all-1.3.2/lib/require_all.rb:109:in `block in require_all'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/require_all-1.3.2/lib/require_all.rb:107:in `each'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/require_all-1.3.2/lib/require_all.rb:107:in `require_all'
/Users/djLaX805/RubymineProjects/Learning Ruby on a MAC/test_puppies_one/features/support/env.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.14/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/djLaX805/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts?  I followed along his book exactly the way he has it.

Comment: You might want to add `require 'active_record'` at top of `adoption.rb` as well.

Comment: Can you share the code in `features/support/pages/database/adoption.rb` file. Update it in the question.

Comment: The pages have been labeled.  That is all the code in those files.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem minutes ago and solved it by using the
    rails g cucumber:install
command.